# IBM Worklight Developer API for Plugin

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

As you know, IBM has a Worklight service like Microsoft Azure. So I just want to bring worklight to any cross-platform IDE or native sdk as a plugin. How can I success it?

For example check out the Xamarin IBM Worklight plugin. Can I code it by myself for Xamarin or another software development kit (SDK)?

Answer (score 4):

Worklight provides a CLI (command line interface). You can take it and integrate it to any IDE that will allow you to.

CLI documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_wl_cli_features.html

Comment: @HüseyinElmas, Xamarin is an IBM partner, they have a different kind of integration with the Worklight SDK.

Comment: Of course, I know this before asking this question. I just wonder can I code it by myself for Xamarin or others.

Comment: The CLI provides you command line... commands, you could create for example a package for Atom.io that would call the various commands. Again, Xamarin has integrated SDK into the Xamarin IDE via source, not CLI.

Comment: I wanted to get a plugin for an IDE which is developed in my country. I got my answer.